https://custom root domain not working on vercel
Please I need help, I have successfully deployed my next js app on vercel but i have a problem.
I can only access it using https://www.rootdomain.com and www.rootdomain.com
but not with https://rootdomain.com.
.
Please I would appreciate any kind of help because I am getting frustrated
I have tried adding possible dns records but no avail

Not enough information to assist on this one. We would need the domain. This is most likely a DNS misconfiguration or proxy shenanigans.

Depending on where you purchased your domain name from, you could setup a URL redirect directly from the domain provider. For example, if you purchased your domain name from Namecheap, you can setup a permanent redirect from mysite.com to www.mysite.com. Ensure that only www.mysite.com is configured on Vercel, though.
This fixed it for me on most of my domains but the problem is when the domain is not purchased from Namecheap or when the domain provider doesn't allow for direct redirect.
